# (Sequelize) Product category enum values from Category model

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have `ProductCategory` and `Category` models. What is the right way to make `category` field of `ProductCategory` be one of `category_name` values in `Category` model? (`Category` model is a set of permitted `category` values)

**models/product-category.js**

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../utils/database');


const ProductCategory = sequelize.define('product_category', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  category: { // `category` values should be one of `category_name` values

    // type: Sequelize.ENUM(...categories),
    // defaultValue: defaultValue,
  },

}, {
  freezeTableName: true
});


module.exports = ProductCategory;
```

**models/category.js**

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../utils/database');

const options = [
  'sale', 'lease', 'others'
];

const Category = sequelize.define('category', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  category_name: {
    type: Sequelize.ENUM(...options),
    defaultValue: defaultValue
  },
  
}, {
  freezeTableName: true
});


module.exports = Category;
```

Later on, I will probably have associations like this:

```js
Product.hasOne(ProductCategory);
ProductCategory.belongsTo(Product);

ProductCategory.belongsTo(Category);
Category.hasMany(ProductCategory);
```

I'm wondering whether I'm heading at the right direction